# How to specify ReadCapacityUnits when querying a DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am querying DynamoDB from python and I would like to specify max ReadCapacityUnits that the query should use.

For example, my table has 100 ReadCapacityUnits, I would like to use only 5% of it which is 20.

Below is my query, how can I specify ReadCapacityUnits in this query

```
paginator = ddb_client.get_paginator('query')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(TableName=table_name,
                                       IndexName=INDEX_GSI,
                                       KeyConditionExpression=condition,
                                       ExpressionAttributeNames={ATTR_NAME: HASH_KEY},
                                       ExpressionAttributeValues={
                                           PLACEHOLDER: {'S': str(value)},
                                       },
                                       ConsistentRead=False,
                                       ScanIndexForward=False,
                                       PaginationConfig={"PageSize": 25})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

How big are your records?

Since an RCU is a read of *up to* 4KB of data (per second), and you specified a page size of 25, you'd have to have records larger than about 160 bytes for your query to consume more than 1 RCU.

Lets say your records are 1K, so for each RCU, you can read 4.  Since your page size is 25, that would take only 7 RCU.

Key thing here is you're not using a filter express.  (Good!)

With a filter express, you still pay for the data to be read even if it's not returned.

Also note that DDB will only read 1MB of data, before returning.  (Even if all records are filtered out).  This is why SCAN() as opposed to Query() can eat up your RCU.